# Bypass Google Recaptcha for imacros

Tags: javascript, recaptcha, captcha, imacros

FCI: iMB v12.6 'Trial', Win10_x32

Hi
Please accept my honor and love in advance.

```
VERSION BUILD=601105 RECORDER=FX
```

`SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 0`

`SET !ERRORIGNORE YES`

`TAB T=1`

`SET !DATASOURCE data.csv`

`SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 1`

`SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}}`

`URL GOTO=https://www.google.com/search?&q={{!COL1}}`

`WAIT SECONDS=1`

`TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=ID:result-stats EXTRACT=TXT`
   `SET result EVAL("var s=\"{{!extract}}\";s=s.replace(/,/g,\"\");s=s.split(\" \");s[1];")`

`SET !EXTRACT NULL`
   `ADD !EXTRACT {{result}}`

`SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=D:\mizanrobi\output-files FILE=result.csv`
WAIT SECONDS=3`

I am using above code to extract google search result as csv format. The code has no issue. Problem is after running the loops 7 times or generally 13 times or any random times captcha comes (I am not robot) and I need pause the loop to solve captcha manually. I am expecting to implement captcha solution in my code so each time captcha comes imacros solve it automatically and the the code runs without interrupt . I am using csv file as input to run google search which contain 2000+ rows so it's very much time consuming to solve captcha manually. Another thing, I am only able to use .iim file for imacros.

Thank You

FCI: iMB v12.6 'Trial', Win10_x32

Comment: Ask google if they let you pass :)

Comment: thanks for great suggestion. So kind of you.